# Use CSS Grid to fit the red field into the red border in Grid Attack level 77

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid, css-grid

I got stuck on Coding Fantasy: Grid Attack level 77 for hours. I tried everything and nothing worked so far. The game provides no solutions, and I can’t skip the level. Does anyone know the solution please?

I need to fit the red land into the red border in the image below using **grid-auto-rows** **align-content** and **span**.

CSS

```
#field {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 1fr);
  /* type here */
  
}

#field div:nth-child(3n) {
  /* type here */
  
}
```

> HTML

```
<div id="field">
  <div class="greenLand"></div>
  <div class="redLand"></div>
  <div class="greenLand"></div>
  <div class="redLand"></div>
  <div class="greenLand"></div>
  <div class="redLand"></div>
</div>
```

i tried all possible values but it did'nt work

Answer (score 0):

Its really late but if you're curious this is it.

Really proud that I solved this without looking it up. except the docs.

Honestly its not that the problem is hard but the initial code given to you was wrong and the grid graphic does not show the height of the rows. I had to eyeball it.

```
#field {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 1fr);
  /* type here */
  grid-auto-rows: 100px;
  gap: 15px;
  align-content: space-between;
}
  
#field div:nth-child(3n) {
  /* type here */
  grid-column: span 3; 
}
```

**grid template columns**: it was set to *auto-fill* but that just makes the items take up all the space. set it to *auto-fit*

**grid-auto-rows**: I eyeballed it and guessed the height.

The rest are pretty self explanatory.